# English translation for "廢"?

Tags: translation

For example,

> 我廢了你

It can roughly translate to "I'll waste/break/ruin you", but that doesn't sound too accurate.

What "廢" sounds like is kindof like "crippling" yet less severe than that.

From what I can tell, it sounds like extreme, violent damage yet nothing as permanent as crippling.

Comment: Wasting sounds right to me as the lesser version of crippling.

Answer (score 3):

废 is a slang, and as NS.X mentioned, "waste" is a pretty good translation, as in

> I'mma waste you

Nonetheless, IMHO, 废 doesn't necessarily mean waste. Other meanings include:

- What you thought it is, "to cripple".
- "To destroy (life, job, etc)", as in

  > 我废了你（的人生）
  >
  > I'mma destroy your life

Answer (score 1):

废 is slang for beat up, to hurt someone badly.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order makes more sense. 我废了你 = 我 make 你 废了。

I'll make you crap. Something like that. It just likes the ancient Chinese grammar.

Answer (score 0):

How about `I'll tear you (up).`
`废` means `disable sb.` here, so `tear up` may be an appropriate expression.